# Is there a way to extend a ::before vertically in a fixed element?

Tags: css, sass

The `::before` selector doesn't extend vertically in a fixed element.

Is there a way to make the background fill the whole height? Now, when a user scrolls, the `::before` elemeent stops as soon as the user has scrolled outside the viewport.

Preferably a **non-javascript** way.

Thanks in advance.

*NB: I'm using SASS, feel free to provide an answer in SCSS or just plain CSS.*

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/u7fvb2nq/

Snippet:

```
.outer
  position: fixed
  &::before
    content: ''
    position: absolute
    left: 0
    top: 0
    bottom: 0
    right: 0
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use position fixed for **:before** pseudo element.

```css
.outer{
  position: fixed;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473830394358-91588751b241?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 30px;
}
.outer:before{
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4));
} 
    
.outer p{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    max-width: 400px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eu dignissim felis, sit amet ultricies justo. Praesent consequat at nulla nec eleifend. Sed convallis, metus non pellentesque elementum, nunc arcu condimentum leo, sit amet pellentesque turpis augue ac sapien. Phasellus facilisis lacinia mauris at consectetur. Morbi sapien augue, condimentum vel erat vitae, semper rutrum erat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum porttitor pharetra faucibus. Donec lobortis massa id dui porta aliquam. Integer eu velit lacinia, cursus libero in, vulputate ligula. Ut ut vestibulum nunc. Nulla facilisi. In turpis augue, luctus pellentesque nibh vel, ullamcorper feugiat orci. Mauris ut metus nec mauris venenatis viverra ut eu mi. Integer quis sem sed tortor dignissim lobortis et at dui. Proin pretium id lectus non semper.dfsdf</p>
</div>
```